# Swapping two letters in a string using recursion

Tags: python, string, recursion

I'm trying to swap two given letters in a given string. I've gotten to the point where my code will replace letter1 (the original letter) with letter2(a new given letter). However, if letter2 occurs in the string, I can't seem to swap it with letter1.

Here is my code.

```
def swap(letter1, letter2,s): 
    if s == "":
        return ""
    else:
        smallerString = s[1:]
        smallerAnswer = swap(letter1,letter2,smallerString)
        firstLetter = s[0]
        if firstLetter == letter1:
            return letter2 + smallerAnswer
        else:
            return firstLetter + smallerAnswer
```

I know I must be missing some kind of additional statement, but every one I try to test out seems to not work either

Comment: Unrelated to the question: you have a duplicate call there. You could reuse the `smallerAnswer` instead of writing the `swap(` call again

Comment: Please fix the indentation it isn't clear

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?  This is just an incredibly inefficient way of doing this.  This algorithm is O(n^2) instead of O(n).

Comment: Yes it was. I definitely agree. Some of the problems my teacher gives me are (in my opinion)  bad examples of how to solve something. Especially in this case where recursion would only make the code more clunky. But I guess the practice is good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a case to swap 1 to 2, and another case for 2 to 1, then a default case to just keep current letter and continue the recursion.

```
def swap(letter1, letter2, s):
    if s == '':
        return ''
    firstLetter = s[0]
    if firstLetter == letter1:
        return letter2 + swap(letter1, letter2, s[1:])
    elif firstLetter == letter2:
        return letter1 + swap(letter1, letter2, s[1:])
    else:
        return firstLetter + swap(letter1, letter2, s[1:])

>>> swap('a', 'b', 'acbxyzbca')
'bcaxyzacb'
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for! Knew I must've been missing an additional elif statement